# Parametric Equations of a Circle

Tags: calculus

> Find parametric equations to go around the unit circle with speed
>   $e^t$ starting from $x=1$, $y=0$. When is the circle completed?

**Why is the book leaving out the constant of integration when solving this problem, or what am I missing?**

Here's my work:

parametric equations of the unit circle are:
$x = r\cos(t) = 1\cos(t)$ and
$y = r\sin(t) = 1\sin(t)$.

Because $\lvert v\rvert$ (speed) is $e^t$ I will have to adjust the parameter $t$ so I will set this new parameter as $w$ giving me my position function of:
$$R(t) = \cos(w)i + \sin(w)j.$$
Hence,
$$v = R'(t) = -(dw/dt)\sin(w)i + (dw/dt)\cos(w)j,$$
and so
$$\lvert v\rvert = dw/dt,$$
which gives $dw/dt = e^t$

To find $w$ I integrate $dw/dt$ giving $w = e^t + c$.  Plugging this into my position function gives:
$$R(t) = \cos(e^t + c)i + \sin(e^t + c)j.$$
Since we know the starting position is $x=1$, $y=0$, we have
$\cos(1+c)=1$ and $\sin(1+c)=0$.  Hence, $1+c = 0$, so $c = -1$.

**the final $R(t)$ should be:
$$R(t) = \cos(e^t - 1)i + \sin(e^t - 1)j,$$
however, the book says the answer is $R(t) = \cos(e^t)i + \sin(e^t)j$.**

When is the circle completed?  Since we know  $\lvert v\rvert = e^t$, we integrate it to find distance giving 
$$\int \lvert v\rvert = e^t + c$$
and $e^t + c = 0$.
$c = -1$.

$e^t -1  = 2\pi$.

**this should give:
$$t = \ln(2\pi + 1).$$
however, the book says the answer is $t = \ln(2\pi)$.**

Comment: I'm finding hard to understand what you did: first, what do you need that weird $\,\omega\,$ for? You only need $\,e^t\,$ ! Second, beginning at $\,x=1,y=0\,$ just means beginning at $\,t=0\Longrightarrow x=\cos 0=1\,\,,\,y=\sin 0=0\,$ ...!

Comment: Your right you don't need the ω I just plugged it in there to make it easier for me, yep I got that part I should have been more clear that's how I got cos(1 + c) = 1 and sin(1+c) = 0 from cos(e^(1)+c) = 1 and sin(e^(1) + c) = 0

Answer (score 1):

The book probably has a misprint. Unroll the circular path to the line segment $[0,2\pi]$ on the $x$-axis, we have $dx/dt=e^t$ and hence $x(t)=e^t+C$. As $x(0)=0$, we have $C=-1$ and hence $x(t)=e^t-1$. Therefore $x(t)=2\pi$ when $t=\ln(1+2\pi)$.